# Apache Flink 1.6.0 connectivity issue with Kafka 1.1.0

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using a cluster of Apache Flink 1.6.0. We use FlinkKafkaConsumer011 in the job.
Checkpointing is enabled (Statebackend is RocksDB, Interval 5 s, Timeout 1 minute, Minimum pause between checkpoints 1s, Maximum concurrent checkpoints 1. When I execute the job in the local IDE, all is successful. But when the job execute in the remote flink cluster, no events are read (use `startFromEarliest`, I am ensure that there is many event message in kafka topic).By watch the job log, there is no ERROR log, only find some WARN message:

`WARN  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher  - Committing offsets to Kafka takes longer than the checkpoint interval. Skipping commit of previous offsets because newer complete checkpoint offsets are available. This does not compromise Flink's checkpoint integrity.`

Should I ignore these warnning message? Why the flink kafka connector read events from earliest offset?

Comment: Can you enable DEBUG level logging on the Kafka client in order to get some more insights?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Thank you for your tips. When I enable DEBUG level logging on the kafka and flink, I find the important reason.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Thank you for your tips. When I enable DEBUG level logging on the kafka and flink, I find the important reason. It cannot be seen when INFO level logging.
```
java.io.IOException: Can't resolve address: kafka2:9092
    ...
```
So I modify and config the `/etc/hosts` file which in flink cluster nodes. That it's right for the flink job. I am confused that why should I add the mapping of domain an kafka's node IP in flink cluster node's `hosts` file? I think kafka client can access the broker by IP directly(like use elasticsearch client).